# Reserved Keywords -- Hidden? JNLP

Tags: java, keyword, jnlp, java-web-start, reserved

I was browsing through some details when a thread caught my eye.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9886607

As you can see; `&TOKEN=something` in JNLP href is considered a special keyword and &token works. I am not really sure if this is the case. But thought of browsing the oracle site to get more details on these '`keywords`'. Could not find any reference to this '`TOKEN`'. So was wondering is there a list of keywords we are not supposed to use in JNLP href? Anyone know if its officially published somewhere? Or could suggest a way to try and search for those in local java installation?

Comment: It probably isn't reserved as much as used in an internal, app-breaking-if-modified manner.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude much at all from that thread.  I didn't think so when I contributed to it.

Answer (score 2):

That I know of there are only 3 magic tokens you can use in fields. $$codebase, $$context and $$name. They are replaced when the script is executed. If I recall $$codebase generates the location of the jnlp file, $$name is the jnlp file name and I have no idea what $$context is.

I never heard of an &TOKEN however.